# 2-way communication between iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am fully aware of the `window.postMessage` method for sending a message to another iframe, but I would like to retrieve an answer from the receiving window that the message was successfully received. I would like it to act more like an AJAX call, with success and failure callbacks, something like this:

```
window.postMessage(myMessage)
      .success(mySuccessCallback)
      .failure(myFailureCallback);
```

I obviously understand that if both iframes are in the same domain I can access them directly, but it would not be asynchronous and it would not cover the case where the iframes are not on the same domain.

So, is it doable?

Comment: Have a look at `event.source.postMessage(message, event.origin);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: As I said, I am fully aware of `postMessage`, but as others have noted below, it's one way communication. Is there something in particular on the MDN article that says otherwise?

Comment: It tells you how to reply directly to the sender.

Comment: I'm afraid you missed my point, I want to attach a callback so that if/when I get a reply, I fire the callback function, and if I don't, I fire the failure callback function. As I said, the examples are all about one-way communication.

Comment: There is no mechanism.  You need to create it yourself.  I suggest using the method I posted so you can reply to the sender.

Answer (score 1):

`postMessage` is fire and forget. If you want to know if the message was received then the the other document needs to post its own message back.

i.e.

1. Page A sends message to Page B
2. Page B has event listener that fires when it gets a message

   - Said event listener sends message to Page A
3. Page A has event listener that fires when it gets a message

Comment: I thought about that, but it doesn't allow me to add callbacks in a nice and clean way, I have to add event listeners on both sides manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an id to it, to make the source clearer, however you cannot check if a connection fails. Alternatively you could ping the other side often to see if their is a connection. If you dont need a failure you could do:

```
var communicators={};
function communicator(id){
this.myid=id;
communicators[id]=this;
this.listeners=[];
}
communicator.prototype.post=function(data){
window.postMessage({data:data,id:this.myid});

 return this;
 }
communicator.prototype.done=function(func){
this.listeners.push(func);
return this;
}
communicators.prototype.fire(data){
this.listeners.forEach((listener)=>{listener(data)});
this.listeners=[];
}

window.addEventListener("message",function(event){
//todo: check event.origin
communicators[event.data.id].fire(event.data.data);
}
```

Use like:
Sender:

```
conn1=new communicator("broadcast");
conn1.post("Hi").done(function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

And on the receiver side:

```
conn=new communicator("broadcast");
conn.done(func);
```

Both sides must use the same id...

Comment: This looks nice, but I *do* need failure. Maybe I can get away with assuming that failure will be triggered if I don't receive an acknowledgment message from the receiver within, say, 3 seconds. I guess I can add a timeout for that somewhere in your code. I'll have a look, thanks.